# parallax fading one div into another with Skrollr

Tags: jquery, scroll, background-image, fade, parallax

I am trying to fade 3 (fullscreen) divs into one another as I scroll.

I have been trying to use Skrollr ( https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr ) and it has kind of worked but with one weird issue.

When I scroll down the images fade but '.intro-bg' starts at the top of the page and then moves to about half way down the page. '.sign-up-bg' is fine and doesn't scroll it stays fixed to the top, and so does 'welcome-bg'. So it's just the middle one being a pain.

I created a fiddle to try replicate things http://jsfiddle.net/9HFd9/ it's not quite the same but there are scroll issues here too.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="welcome">Welcome</div>
    <div class="intro">Intro</div>
    <div class="sign-up">Sign Up</div>
</div>
<div class="welcome-bg" data-0="opacity:1;" data-500="opacity:0;"></div>
<div class="intro-bg" data-500="opacity:1;" data-1000="opacity:0;"></div>
<div class="sign-up-bg" ></div>
```

Javascript:

```
skrollr.init({
    smoothScrolling: true,
    forceHeight: false
});

var maxWidth = $(window).width();
var maxHeight = $(window).height();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.welcome, .intro, .sign-up').css({
        width: maxWidth,
        height: maxHeight
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.welcome-bg, .intro-bg, .sign-up-bg{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;

  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.welcome-bg{
    background: blue url('http://wallpicshd.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Landscape-04-HD-Wallpaper.jpg') center center fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    z-index:-2;
}
.intro-bg{
  background: green url('http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/sunflower_landscape-wide.jpg') center center fixed;
  z-index:-3;
}
.sign-up-bg{
  background: red url('http://www.hdwallpaperstop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Beautiful-Landscape-Pictures-of-nature.jpg') center center fixed;
  z-index:-4;
}
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I don't see any issues in the fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="welcome-bg" data-0="opacity:1;" data-100p="opacity:0;"></div>
<div class="intro-bg" data-100p="opacity:1;" data-200p="opacity:0;"></div>
```

and add

```
 $( window ).resize(function() {
 var maxWidth = $(window).width();
 var maxHeight = $(window).height();
 $('.welcome, .intro, .sign-up').css({
        width: maxWidth,
        height: maxHeight
});   
});
```

Look: http://jsfiddle.net/58s7c1sf/

Comment: Please include the resize function snippet in the body of the answer instead of merely linking to it. Links move/die and otherwise become unavailable over long periods of time.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at https://gist.github.com/pascalmaddin/5756515

It is very simple and i hope it will help you to

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer however please provide context for links: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline - from [How to provide a good answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)